# LINQ, Select record from List where its reference exist IN IQueryable<T> C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, entity-framework-6

I need to perform Select where it exist IN List operation in LINQ or Lambda. I am have number of try with .Contains but no result, I have no idea what I am missing here...

```
so in SQL select * where unit-code in (select unit-code, organisation ... group by unit-code, organisation
```

### Sort-Listed Class Model 1

```
public class UnitInstanceOccurrenceCode
{ 
    public string FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE { get; set; }

    public string OWNING_ORGANISATION { get; set; }
}
```

### ViewModel for 2nd Query

```
public class ActiveUnitInstancesViewModel
 {
    public UnitInstancesEntity UnitInstances { get; set; }
    public UnitInstanceOccurrencesEntity UnitInstanceOccurrences { get; set;}
    public VerifierEntity Verifiers { get; set; }
    public OrganisationUnitEntity OrganisationUnits { get; set; }

}
```

### Query 1

```
 IQueryable<UnitInstanceOccurrenceCode> ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES = _uow.UnitInstanceOccurrencesRepository.GetAll()
     .Where(u => u.STATUS != "WITHDRAWN" && u.STATUS != "INACTIVE")
     .GroupBy(g => new { g.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE, g.OWNING_ORGANISATION })
     .Select(uio => new UnitInstanceOccurrenceCode
         {
          FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE =  uio.Key.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE,
          OWNING_ORGANISATION = uio.Key.OWNING_ORGANISATION
         }
    )
    .Distinct();
```

Above query does works, I have tested it by adding ToList() in another query; refer following screen shot

[image]

### 2nd Query where need help

```
var query = (from ui in _uow.UnitInstancesRepository.GetAll()
                  .Where(x => ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES.Select(code => code.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE)
                  .Contains(x.FES_UNIT_INSTANCE_CODE))
             select ui).ToList();
```

### Error

```
{"Unable to cast the type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[[App.Entities.UnitInstanceOccurrenceCode, App.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' to type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[[App.Entities.UnitInstanceOccurrenceCode, App.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."}
```

[image]

### ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES.ToString();

```
SELECT 
1 AS "C1", 
"Distinct1"."FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE" AS "FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE", 
"Distinct1"."OWNING_ORGANISATION" AS "OWNING_ORGANISATION"
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT 
   "Extent1"."FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE" AS "FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE", 
   "Extent1"."OWNING_ORGANISATION" AS "OWNING_ORGANISATION"
FROM "FES"."UNIT_INSTANCE_OCCURRENCES" "Extent1"
WHERE (( NOT (('WITHDRAWN' = "Extent1"."STATUS") AND ("Extent1"."STATUS" IS NOT NULL))) AND ( NOT (('INACTIVE' = "Extent1"."STATUS") AND ("Extent1"."STATUS" IS NOT NULL))))
 )  "Distinct1"
```

Comment: What does return `ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES.GetType().ToString()`?

Comment: I get System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[App.Entities.UnitInstanceOccurrenceCode]

Comment: I have test code var ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES with single value in it which is not strongly typed, worked in 2nd query off-course removing select(code => code.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE)...

Comment: I need to find way to cast value where I am saying ACTIVE_COURSE_INSTANCE_CODES.Select(code => code.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE) from strongly data type to string or char type then I think it will work

Comment: I have found answer but still want to do all in single line, what I meant is .. using (UnitInstanceOccurrenceCodeObject.Select(code => code.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE));
in my 2nd query that is ... var query =// code

Comment: Sorry, I don't have your model in order to test your query. Tried to build a similar query structure on my EF test data and it works w/o any problem (EF6.1.3, SqlServer is that matters).

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to work this as following, I have to split (UnitInstanceOccurrenceCodeObject.Select(code => code.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE)) in separate variable not sure why it didn't work as it in same query but finally got solution

```
   IQueryable<UnitInstanceOccurrenceCode> UnitInstanceOccurrenceCodeObject = _uow.UnitInstanceOccurrencesRepository.GetAll()
      .Where(u => u.STATUS != "WITHDRAWN" && u.STATUS != "INACTIVE")
      .GroupBy(g => new { g.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE, g.OWNING_ORGANISATION })
      .Select(uio => new UnitInstanceOccurrenceCode
         {
           FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE = uio.Key.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE,
           OWNING_ORGANISATION = uio.Key.OWNING_ORGANISATION
         }
                                                                )
       .Distinct();

 var ActiveUnitInstanceCodes = (UnitInstanceOccurrenceCodeObject.Select(code => code.FES_UINS_INSTANCE_CODE));

 var query = (from ui in _uow.UnitInstancesRepository.GetAll().Where(x => ActiveUnitInstanceCodes.Contains(x.FES_UNIT_INSTANCE_CODE))
                      select ui).ToList();
```